# Remove Another Website Data In Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

There was a mistake and we used one `google analytics` script in two different websites. We removed the script from one of the sites but because of this mistake we now have a lot of invalid data.

How can I remove the data of the other website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cant remove data already in the reports. General "best practice" is to leave the default All Website Data view without any filters applied, and then create one (or more) reporting views (depending on reporting needs) and apply an Include Hostname filter. This prevents data from invalid hostnames ending up in reports (such as in this instance).

To view the historical report data without the erroneous site data included, you can create and apply a segment to only include sessions (or users) for hostname yourdomain.com